# Is linear space a banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals

Is $(X, || . ||)$ with $X = C([0,1])$ and $||f|| = \left( \int_0^1 |f(s)|^{3} dx \right)^{\tfrac{1}{3}}$ a banach space?

It is obvious that this norm is homogeneous and $X$ is a linear space, but I have a problem with convergence of Cauchy sequences.

Comment: $C[0,1]$ is complete with respect to the norm $||.||_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this space is not complete. Define $f_n \colon [0,1] \to \mathbf R$ by 
$$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & x \le \frac 12- \frac 1n \\
                         n(x-\frac12) & \frac 1n - \frac 1n \le x \le \frac 12 + \frac 1n\\
         1 & x \ge \frac 12 + \frac 1n
\end{cases} 
$$
Then $(f_n)$ is Cauchy, note that $f_n$ and $f_m$ only differ on a set of length $\frac 2{\min\{n,m\}}$, that is
$$ \|f_n - f_m\| \le 2^{1/3}\cdot 2 \frac1{\min\{n,m\}^{1/3}} \to 0, \qquad n,m \to \infty $$
But $(f_n)$ cannot converge to a continuos function in norm, has either positive or non-negative values near $\frac 12$, hence bounded below distance to all $(f_n)$.